# How can I avoid widgets being added repeatedly when calling SetState?

Tags: flutter

Im reading data from a firebase and inserts the items in a list. Based on the number of items I create widgets in dynamically lists to manipulate the data. The problem is that when build is called my lists will add the widgets in the lists again and again every time I called SetState.

I can not clear the list as it contain data that is manipulated and hence I would lose the data. What is the right architectural or best practise to handle this ?

It is when I add the widgets to the registrationList I have the problem

```
 Widget buildTable() {
    int outerRange = projectMap.length + 4;
    double rowSum = 0;

    return Table(
        columnWidths: const {
          0: FlexColumnWidth(2),
          1: FlexColumnWidth(1),
          2: FlexColumnWidth(1),
          3: FlexColumnWidth(1),
          4: FlexColumnWidth(1),
          5: FlexColumnWidth(1),
          6: FlexColumnWidth(1),
          7: FlexColumnWidth(1),
          8: FlexColumnWidth(1),
        },
        children: List<TableRow>.generate(outerRange, (rowIndex) {
          return TableRow(
              children: List<TableCell>.generate(9, (columnIndex) {
            // Project Title
            if (rowIndex == 1 && columnIndex == 0) {
              return TableCell(
                child: Text(
                  S.of(context).projectName,
                  style: defaultTextStyleBold(defaultColor, (14)),
                ),
              );
            } else if (rowIndex == 0 && columnIndex > 0 && columnIndex < 8) {
              // Title of Date name
              return TableCell(
                  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  child: ColoredBox(
                    color: getColour(dateClassList[columnIndex - 1]),
                    child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(dateClassList[columnIndex - 1].weekDay,
                            style: defaultTextStyleBold(defaultColor, (14)))),
                  ));
            } else if (rowIndex == 1 && columnIndex == 8) {
              // Total Title
              return TableCell(
                  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [buildTotalHeaderWidget()]));
            } else if (rowIndex == 1 && columnIndex > 0 && columnIndex < 8) {
              // Title of dates
              return TableCell(
                  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  child: ColoredBox(
                      color: getColour(dateClassList[columnIndex - 1]),
                      child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text("  ${dateClassList[columnIndex - 1].dateDay}  ",
                              style: defaultTextStyle(defaultColor, 14)))));
            } else if (rowIndex == 2) {
              // Divider
              return const TableCell(
                child: Divider(
                  thickness: 1,
                  color: defaultColor,
                ),
              );
            } else if (rowIndex > 2 && rowIndex < outerRange - 1 && columnIndex == 0) {
              // project name list
              return TableCell(
                  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.bottom,
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(projectMap.values.elementAt(rowIndex - 3)!.projectName,
                            style: defaultTextStyleBold(defaultColor, (14))),
                        Text(customerMap[projectMap.values.elementAt(rowIndex - 3)!.customerOwner]!.customerName,
                            style: defaultTextStyle(defaultColor, 14)),
                        const Divider(
                          thickness: 1,
                          color: gridColor,
                        ),
                      ]));
            } else if (rowIndex > 2 && rowIndex < outerRange - 1 && columnIndex < 8) {
              // Registration widget
              registrationList.add([
                TextEditingController(),
                TextEditingController(),
                TextEditingController(),
                TextEditingController(),
                TextEditingController(),
                TextEditingController(),
                TextEditingController(),
              ]);
              totalFields.add(0.0);
              descriptionTextControllers.add([
                TextEditingController(),
                TextEditingController(),
                TextEditingController(),
                TextEditingController(),
                TextEditingController(),
                TextEditingController(),
                TextEditingController(),
              ]);
              totalFields[rowIndex - 3] = double.parse(calculateTotalHours(rowIndex - 3));
              return TableCell(
                  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        buildRegistrationWidget(rowIndex - 3, columnIndex - 1),
                        const Divider(
                          thickness: 1,
                          color: gridColor,
                        ),
                      ]));
            } else if (rowIndex > 2 && rowIndex < outerRange - 1 && columnIndex == 8) {
              // Total widget
              return TableCell(
                  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        buildTotalWidget(rowIndex - 3),
                        const Divider(
                          thickness: 1,
                          color: gridColor,
                        ),
                      ]));
            } else if (rowIndex == outerRange - 1 && columnIndex == 7 && outerRange > 4) {
              return TableCell(
                  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    color: defaultColor,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Text(S.of(context).saveButtonText),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        saveData();
                        //Navigator.pop(context);
                      });
                    },
                  ));
            } else {
              return const TableCell(
                child: Text(""),
              );
            }
          }));
        }));
  }

  Widget gridContent() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(children: [
          Expanded(flex: 3, child: dateNavigatorButtons()),
          Expanded(flex: 7, child: dateCalendarButtons())
        ]),
        buildTable(),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    dateClassList = createWeekDays(displayDate);
    
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: getProjectsByCompanyID,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Something went wrong'),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          for (var object in snapshot.data!.docs) {
            projectMap[object.id] = Project.fromQueryDocumentSnapshot(object);
          }
          projectMap.removeWhere(
            (key, value) => compareEndDate(value!),
          );
        }
        return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: getCustomerByCompanyID,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Center(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Something went wrong'),
                ),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              for (var object in snapshot.data!.docs) {
                customerMap[object.id] = Customer.fromQueryDocumentSnapshot(object);
              }
            }
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                leading: Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
                    );
                  },
                ),
                actions: generateAppMenuBar(context, widget.appUser, cCustomerScreen),
                backgroundColor: defaultColor,
              ),
              body: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Row(children: [
                  const Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("")),
                  Expanded(flex: 8, child: gridContent()),
                  const Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("")),
                ]),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why are you reading from database every build? Shouldn't it be done only in `initState`?

Comment: bc I use StreamBuilder. Im not sure I can do that in InitState. But even though I move it to initState I still have the problem that Widgets are added to my list every time build Is called

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be adding anything to a list in the build. Because as you can see it will just add up then. But it's hard to help without seeing more code

Comment: ok I'll add the code - can't see how I can prevent adding in the build :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the best way is to do it, but possibly you can check if `registrationList[rowIndex - 1]` is null before you add them and only add them when it's null

Comment: Thanks - it worked even though I'm not sure if it good practices